# Virt-Manager "Host does not support any virtualization options" all of a sudden, don't know what happened?

Tags: centos, virtual-machine

I've created two virtual machines using virt-manager and now when I try to create a new virtual machine, I get the message "Host does not support any virtualization options". The previous two virtual machines that I have successfully ran before also refuse to start giving me the message instead in the image

[image]

Details

```
Error starting domain: internal error: Failed to start QEMU binary /usr/libexec/qemu-kvm for probing: qemu-kvm: cannot initialize crypto: Unable to initialize gcrypt


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 75, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 111, in tmpcb
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/libvirtobject.py", line 66, in newfn
    ret = fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/domain.py", line 1279, in startup
    self._backend.create()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 1234, in create
    if ret == -1: raise libvirtError ('virDomainCreate() failed', dom=self)
libvirt.libvirtError: internal error: Failed to start QEMU binary /usr/libexec/qemu-kvm for probing: qemu-kvm: cannot initialize crypto: Unable to initialize gcrypt
```

EDIT

### Solution

please see this link for fix thanks to @jsbillings for solution

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1840485

my version of qemu-kvm was
qemu-kvm-4.2.0-34
and had
libgcrypt-1.8.3-4
and after updating libgcrypt to
libgcrypt-1.8.5-4
fixed this issue

Comment: See, for example, https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-virtualization-and-cloud-90/virt-install-error-host-does-not-support-any-virtualization-options-4175483456/.

Comment: I think this is actually related to this bug: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1840485

Comment: @jsbillings yup that fixed it, thank you